# Remove numbers from middle of filename

Tags: powershell, batch-file, batch-rename

I have 400 tif files with names similar to:

- 121941_006419_INDUNC.tif
- 121948_007193_DRILLG.tif
- 121950_007321_INDUNC.tif

that I need to have an underscore and 6 random numbers removed to look like:

- 121941_INDUNC.tif
- 121948_DRILLG.tif
- 121950_INDUNC.tif

I have searched and the only solutions I have found involve downloading software which my company does not permit.

Is there a way to use a batch file to remove those seven characters from these files?

Comment: I somehow doubt that this question is about DOS (as in Disk Operating System). Neither the Windows Command Prompt nor PowerShell have anything to do with that.

Comment: DOS and Command Prompt are often used interchangeably. I think most folks realize what's being talked about.

Comment: Ansgar sorry for the lack of proper vocabulary about DOS. I did mean the Command Prompt. As for the duplicate, that post did not answer my question because it searched for the same character in each file, and my files had 6 random numbers in each file bracketed by underscores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) tag, here a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) solution:

Use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to retrieve your files filtered by `.tif` and rename them using the `Rename-Item` cmdlet with a simple regex replace:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\tmp -Filter '*.tif' | 
   Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '_\d+' }
```

Comment: Thank you Martin. Your code worked perfectly and solved my problem.  I do not understand what _\d+ means. Any chance you could explain that?

Comment: gci -Path c:\temp -File -Filter "*.tif" | foreach{$arr=$_.name -split "_"; Rename-Item $_.FullName  ($_.DirectoryName + "\" + $arr[0] + "_" + $arr[2]) }

Comment: @ThomasWard `_\d+` is a regular expression matching "*an underscore, followed by one or more digits*". See [here](https://regex101.com/r/5LQIVY/1) how it matches against your filenames.